How can I remove/omit/filter-out thumbnail previews from Google search results with Firefox on macOS?
The left-column-anchored thumbnail results are cognitively disrupting for me, dragging my eye away from the traditional text-titled search results. Not just inefficient for me, they also throw off my ability to quickly find relevant results.






I want them removed or hidden from view. I have looked under advanced search terms/operators but have not been able to find a solution. If there are extension suggestions or about:config custom CSS code solutions, please note that I only use Firefox on desktop, so hopefully there are solves.

I’d think this is a site-specific choice (aka there’s nothing you can do about it.) You might have some luck with a browser extension, however.

This is nearly impossible as Google uses randomized element names and often changes structure of their HTML to prevent scraping etc. Much easier to just focus on what you want to focus on

No, you presume too much. I have ADHD. Go and laugh and be smug but it's an actual disability and that is what I am saying. It obviously doesn't matter to you so therefore my desire is absurd.
